# How to fix door touching frame

Tags: door-frame

I have this bathroom door which is touching the frame at the point I highlighted in this image. I am not able to figure out why. Any idea what might be causing this and how can I fix it?
Thank you
[image: door touching frame here]

Comment: If that picture is showing true, then it looks like the latch side is too tight, the hinge and top side looks almost perfect spacing.  I would probably try a long piece of scrape wood and a 24oz hammer first to suggest the latch side frame move over a bit.

Comment: What’s the reveal at the top of the door look like?

Comment: @crip659 +1 for "to suggest". Ever so polite.

Comment: has this door always rubbed? is it a seasonal problem? Is this a bathroom with a shower in use (moisture)? are all the hinge screws tight? what's the spacing (reveal) at the top (as already asked)?

Comment: I think it’s happening when temperature rises .. this was not there in winter.. most of hinge screw are tight but they are just rotating when I try to tighten them more. Upper spacing looks ok to me

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew the hinge screws at the bottom, on the frame side, not the door.

Replace with 2 inch long screws and tighten.

That should move the door to the left just enough to stop touching the frame. If not repeat the same process for the other door hinges

Comment: If I was going through all that, I would also chisel out the hinge mortise a tad.

Comment: Except that the reveal on the hinge side appears (from here, it's hard to be 100% certain) to be very even. Doing this would make the reveal off on the bottom hinge side.